# Java2EE always uses MVC2 architecture?

Tags: java, asp.net-mvc, jakarta-ee, web, model-view-controller

My question is the following, I want to know if Java EE always uses MVC2 architecture or not.

Comment: Need an answer please, it's important

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is No. Its up to the developer if they want to follow that pattern. Controllers are Servlets in Java EE and views are JSP pages or whatever template engine you choose but where it gets confusing is the model. The developer can put all their business logic inside the controller fusing them together. This is frowned upon but Java EE does not prevent you from doing that. The java pattern is to usually put the logic in a service class that the controller calls, with the Model layer being comprised of services which under the hood may make database calls, call other objects etc etc...Java EE as a framework gives you tools for the "V" and the "C" in MVC but you can drop the the model separation and use just VC but as I said before thats not the practice.

Building a webapp in Java you would rarely use just Java EE by itself these days. There are  MVC frameworks that sit ontop of it that simplify a lot of things "Spring MVC" for one but there are many others.